# Copy span text using Clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboard.js

I'm using clipboard.js and need to copy the text in a span by clicking a button. Is there a way to do this?

HTML:

```
<span id="spanId">text here</span>
<input type="button" class="buttonClass" value="Copy" data-clipboard-target="#spanId" />
```

Comment: why yes. yes there is.

Comment: @Pamblam haha mind elaborating?

Comment: OK with a button, but what about copying the inner text/html of a span tag when the span is selected using the select event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution can be:

```js
// create a new instance of Clipboard plugin for the button element
// using the class selector: .buttonClass
var clipboard =  new Clipboard('.buttonClass');


// when text is copied into clipboard use it
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  $('#log').text('Text copied into clipboard is: <' + e.text + '>');
  e.clearSelection();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<span id="spanId">text here</span>
<input type="button" class="buttonClass" value="Copy" data-clipboard-target="#spanId"/>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll just need to instantiate a new Clipboard. In this case you'd write `new Clipboard(".buttonClass")` because that's the class your button has. The markup you've provided was completely functional otherwise. I've made a JSFiddle that you can view [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pinjasaur/fo5wmgch/).

If you're having any other trouble, I found the [clipboard.js docs](https://clipboardjs.com/) to be very helpful.